# unique validate using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

this is my controller

```
 $rules = [ 
  'Group_Id'=>'required',
  'Group_Code'=>'required', 
  'Group_Name'=>'required| string', 
  'Currency'=>'required', 
  'Country'=>'required', 
  'State'=>'required', 
  'City'=>'required',
]
```

I want group id Group code should be unique while  create if group id /group code already  present in table means I  want to print error as group id/group id  already exit .while updating  don't want to change group  id  filed that's remains same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rules = [ 
  'Group_Id'=>'required|unique:group,id',
  'Group_Code'=>'required|unique:group,code', 
  'Group_Name'=>'required| string', 
  'Currency'=>'required', 
  'Country'=>'required', 
  'State'=>'required', 
  'City'=>'required',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For solving this issue you should add unique identifier in your validation method mentioned as below

```
 $data = $request->validate([
            'Group_Id' => 'required',
            'Group_Code' => 'required|unique:table_name_here',
            'Group_Name' => 'required| string',
            'Currency' => 'required',
            'Country' => 'required',
            'State' => 'required',
            'City' => 'required',
        ]);
```